# How to make a new file based on the updated version of geoJSON file in python?

Tags: python, json, geojson

I've been trying to update a large geoJSON file
I wanted to update all NAME_1 to lowercase and save it in a new file, any ideas how to do it?

This is a part of my geoJSON file 
Theres a large amount of coordinates, so i just cut it off and make it to ....
to simplify the post in here
For the NAME_1 variable theres actually like around 32 of it, and i cut to two only for simplifying purpose, but i need to update all 32

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                ......
             ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "GID_0": "IND",
        "NAME_0": "India",
        "GID_1": "IND.1_1",
        "NAME_1": "Andaman and Nicobar",
        "VARNAME_1": "Andaman & Nicobar Islands|Andaman et Nicobar|Iihas de Andama e Nicobar|Inseln Andamanen und Nikobare",
        "NL_NAME_1": "",
        "TYPE_1": "Union Territor",
        "ENGTYPE_1": "Union Territory",
        "CC_1": "",
        "HASC_1": "IN.AN"
      }
   },
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                ......
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "GID_0": "IND",
        "NAME_0": "India",
        "GID_1": "IND.2_1",
        "NAME_1": "Andhra Pradesh",
        "VARNAME_1": "",
        "NL_NAME_1": "",
        "TYPE_1": "State",
        "ENGTYPE_1": "State",
        "CC_1": "",
        "HASC_1": "IN.AP"
      }
```

And my code:

```
import sys
from geojson import Feature, Point, FeatureCollection, Polygon
import json
import geojson
import pprint
import pandas as pd
import re
import os
#print(sys.version)

with open('gadm36_IND_1.json', 'r') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

for feature in data['features']:
    #change all the Name_1 into lowercase
    name1 = feature['properties']['NAME_1']
    for f in re.findall("([A-Z]+)", name1):
        name1 = name1.replace(f, f.lower())

with open('lower.json', 'w+') as data_file:
    json.dump(data, data_file, indent=2)
```

Fast help please hehehehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to convert the values for key `NAME_1` for all objects in Feature array.

```
import sys
import json
import re
import os

with open('gadm36_IND_1.json', 'r') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

for feature in data['features']:
    # change all the Name_1 into lowercase
    feature['properties']['NAME_1'] = feature['properties']['NAME_1'].lower()

with open('lower.json', 'w+') as data_file:
    json.dump(data, data_file, indent=2)
```

This code turns the value for key `NAME_1` to lowercase and writes new data to file `lower.json`

Below is what my `lower.json` looks like:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "GID_0": "IND",
        "NAME_0": "India",
        "GID_1": "IND.1_1",
        "NAME_1": "andaman and nicobar",
        "VARNAME_1": "Andaman & Nicobar Islands|Andaman et Nicobar|Iihas de Andama e Nicobar|Inseln Andamanen und Nikobare",
        "NL_NAME_1": "",
        "TYPE_1": "Union Territory",
        "ENGTYPE_1": "Union Territory",
        "CC_1": "",
        "HASC_1": "IN.AN"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "GID_0": "IND",
        "NAME_0": "India",
        "GID_1": "IND.2_1",
        "NAME_1": "andhra pradesh",
        "VARNAME_1": "",
        "NL_NAME_1": "",
        "TYPE_1": "State",
        "ENGTYPE_1": "State",
        "CC_1": "",
        "HASC_1": "IN.AP"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value in the original `data['features']`.

So, in the line `name1 = name1.replace(f, f.lower())` replace with `feature['properties']['NAME_1'] = name1.replace(f, f.lower())`.

Another way is by adding this line:
`feature['properties']['NAME_1'] = name1` inside the second loop.

Comment: ahh understood, so i don't need to use another new variable inside the for loop

Comment: yes. But you need to put the value in the existing data so that you can write it again

Answer (score 0):

Using Regular Expression

```
with open('gadm36_IND_1.json') as data_file:
    Json_Str = data_file.read()
NAME_REGEX = re.compile(r'\"NAME_1\":\s*\"(.*?)\"')
for name in NAME_REGEX.findall(Json_Str):
    Json_Str = Json_Str.replace(name , name.lower())
```

Now you have a modified Json string which you can easily convert to json obj